# AVR MCU crashes, no logical error in code. What should I check?

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I am using a megaAVR for an embedded project, coded in C. The device crashes for no apparent reason sometimes. Meaning there is no logical error in the code.

So my question is what are the things to check if you have that type of crashes?

My suggestions:
Stack - Uses too much stack.
Memory - Not applicable, does not use malloc.

More? 
What kind of AVR specific could it be?

Comment: When the device crashes for no apparent reason, it _pretty sure is a logical error in the code_. Honestly, it could be pretty much anything. Are you synchronizing data between ISRs and main code? You're right, check your stack usage. Are there unhandled interrupts? Are interrupts firing too quickly? When your device crashes, can you attach a debugger to find out where it hangs? Do you have uninitialized variables that you use? Do you have dangling pointers somewhere?

Comment: Its a bold claim that there is no code error.  Occam's razor suggests the opposite.  You have [debug hardware](http://store.atmel.com/CBC.aspx?q=c:100112) right?  That's where to start.  I am not sure how not using malloc() implies no memory error - that is a very narrow view of possible memory errors.  I imagine no one is going to usefully attempt to answer such a vague and broad question without evidence of your "perfect code" assertion (i.e. post the code).  Consider buffer overrun and uninitialised indexes and pointers for example.

Comment: Its probably software related but could be caused by hardware issues as well. What is your environment? Are you using a development board? Whats the exact MCU type?

Comment: I would love to see some perfect code as well, please post...

Answer (score 2):

> AVR MCU crashes, [...]. What should I check?

A MCU does not "crash". Either one of a hardware reset conditions is met and causes a defined reset, or its a software related problem causing undefined behavior which just might appear to cause a full reset.

Try to determine IF there is an actual reset happening and potential cause. A first step could be to evaluate the the MCU Control and Status Register MCUCSR. It provides information about the source of the most recent reset.

> To make use of the reset flags to identify a reset condition, the user should read and then reset the MCUCSR as early as possible in the program. If the register is cleared before another reset occurs, the source of the reset can be found by examining the reset flags.

Reset sources:

1. Power-on Reset: Vcc dropped below a min required value
2. External Reset: Low level assertion on reset pin
3. Watchdog Reset: Watchdog timer expired
4. Brown-out Reset: Vcc dropped below the configured brown-out value
5. JTAG AVR Reset: Reset command from JTAG programmer

Check:

- If none of those reset flags is set or your "reset" doesn't even reach the application entry point where you do the check, you look for a software related problem.
- If you don't use the Watchdog yet, do it.
- Check your current static SRAM requirements (use avr-size.exe) and estimate your stack requirements at runtime. You should consider several hundred bytes of safe margin.
- Reduce your code to narrow down the problem.

Comment: **crash != reset**   While that may be the outcome (particularly with a watchdog, or if the trigger is a hardware fault such as a power issue), other likely outcomes are a halt or a runaway program, possibly ending up in a loop somewhere.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I don't see why you point out `crash != reset`, because I don't say anything different in my answer (so why downvote?). Would you mind explaining where you see a problem so I may correct it?

Comment: The downvote is not from me, but your answer is predicated on an actual or apparent reset, which is not the only possible outcome and not a specific symptom which the question states.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: Hmm, I thought that "...software related problem causing undefined behavior which just might appear to cause a full reset." points out that the outcome is not necessarily a reset. - Made a minor edit to the post. I hope thats better.